# request scope with JSTL in JSP

Tags: jstl

I have in JSP

```
<c:set var="reqTypes" value="${requestType }" scope="request" />
```

which I am not able to access in controller

```
String[] requestType = ParamUtil.getParameterValues(req, "reqTypes");
```

I receive "requestType"  as null.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several reasons.

1. The controller tries, if `ParamUtil` and `getParameterValues()` are well named, to access request parameters, but the JSP sets a request attribute. That's not the same thing at all. Parameters are what is sent, as String, by the browser when posting a form (or clicking a link in the form `/foo/bla?param1=value1&param2=value2`). Attributes are arbitrary objects that are stored in the request by the server so that the next component in the request-handling chain can find and use them.
2. The JSP, if the architecture is a classical MVC one, is executed after the controller, and not before, and you're setting request attributes in the JSP. So these attributes disappear as soon as the current request has been handled.